# how to do unit test on functions that take active region as input?

Tags: unit-testing, emacs, elisp

For example, here are two versions of function to count the instances of "a" in a region or in a string:

```
(defun foo (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((count 0))
    (save-excursion
      (while (/= (point) end)
        (if (equal (char-after) ?a)
          (setq count (1+ count)))
        (forward-char)))
  count))

(defun foo1 (str)
  (let ((count 0))
    (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (if (equal x ?a) (setq count (1+ count))))
            str)
  count))
```

This is the test to check the function `foo1`:

```
(require 'ert)
(ert-deftest foo-test ()
  (should (equal (foo1 "aba") 2)))
```

but how can I test the function `foo` that takes a region as input, using `ert` framework of unit testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would second @sds's suggestion, with the added suggestion to do something like:

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert <text>)
  (set-mark <markpos>)
  (goto-char <otherend>)
  (should (equal (call-interactively 'foo) <n>)))
```

Comment: +1. what's the potential advantage of setting mark and using `call-interactively`(besides the fact that it calls `foo` in a situation closer to reality)?

Comment: This variation actually verifies your `interactive` spec. If you had forgotten the `"r"` then using `(call-interactivly 'foo)` woukd give you an error about missing parameters.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert ....) ; prepare the buffer
  (should (equal ... (foo (point-min) (point-max)))))
```